# "maybe in another time" or "maybe in other time"?

Tags: word-choice

What is more appropriate?

1) Maybe in **another** time

2) Maybe in **other** time

The context: 
"I would want to add speaking to this presentation, but I have a lot of studying and I'm busy. Maybe in other time."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe another time.

or

> Maybe some other time.

*in* with *time* is used differently, for example:

> I got there just *in time*.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker I would use a sentence like:

> "I would like to continue speaking about this presentation, but I have a lot of studying to do. Maybe another time"
>   or
>   "I would like to keep going with this presentation, but I have a lot of studying to do. Maybe some other time"

And I would like to stay here and expand my answer, but I have a paper to read. Maybe I can continue later.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the issue is that I'm talking about adding of "voice" (that I called it speaking) to this presentation (video that made of PowerPoint). I hope I explained it well that you can understand me.

Comment: You mean you are going to add narration to your Power Point?